# Styling v-btn when active as a router-link

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How can I style the v-btn when it is active as router-link in vuetify?

```
<div class="mx-n4">
  <v-btn text height="80" class="white--text btn-links" to="/" exact>HOME</v-btn>
  <v-btn text height="80" class="white--text btn-links" to="/events" exact>EVENTS</v-btn>
  <v-btn text height="80" class="white--text btn-links" to="/login" exact>SPEAKERS</v-btn>
  <v-btn text height="80" class="white--text btn-links" to="/location" exact>LOCATION</v-btn>
</div>
```

Here is my VueRouter instance

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  linkActiveClass: "active",
  linkExactActiveClass: "active",
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it's `v-btn--active`:

```
.v-btn--active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or you can set the `active-class` prop on the button:

```
<v-btn text class="white--text btn-links" active-class="active" to="/events" exact>
   EVENTS
</v-btn>
```

https://codeply.com/p/ny44Thdceo